# Continue on Error in PySpark Glue ETL write_dynamic_frame.from_options

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, pyspark, aws-glue

I have a pyspark script executing in an AWS Glue ETL function. I am looking to catch an error, log it, and continue when executing a write_dynamic_frame.from_options. Is this even possible? A try except successfully catches the error, but then stops the processing. I'm looking for a way for the write_dynamic_frame.from_options to continue where it left off after error.

I tried a try except, catching the error, but then processing stops. I also tried the isFailFast parameter, but it didn't seem to do anything.